# Having trouble changing the global variable from within a function (javascript). How can I change cardValue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to build a playing card deck. here's the shortcode for it. I'm just trying to learn still so be gentle on my code.

So I want to create a total value for the cards in a players hand. everytime i try and call this function to change cardValue it doesnt seem to change anything within the global scope.

```
let cardValue = 0;
let cardDeck = [];

for (i=1; 52 >= i; i++) {
    cardDeck.push(i);
};

let card1 = ((Math.random()*52)-1);
card1 = Math.floor(card1);
card1 = cardDeck.splice(card1, 1);

let card2 = ((Math.random()*51)-1);
card2 = Math.floor(card2);
card2 = cardDeck.splice(card2, 1);

function cardTotal(foo, bar) {

    if (3 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 11;
    } else if (7 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 2;
    } else if (11 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 3;
    } else if (15 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 4;
    } else if (19 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 5;
    } else if (23 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 6;
    } else if (27 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 7;
    } else if (31 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 8;
    } else if (35 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 9;
    } else if (39 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 10;
    } else if (43 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 10;
    } else if (47 >= foo) {
        bar =+ 10;
    } else {
        bar =+ 10;
    }

}

cardTotal(card1, cardValue);
cardTotal(card2, cardValue);
console.log(cardValue); // returns 0
```

Comment: The syntax should be `+=` instead of `=+`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions receive primitives by value, not reference.  When your function `cardTotal` receives the value `bar` as one of its arguments, falling into one of your `else` blocks just changes `cardTotal`'s local value for `bar`; but remember since it's a primitive (a `number`) it's been passed by value, so the function only has `cardValue`'s value, not a reference to it.

Slightly Better: inside of `cardTotal`, only take one argument (`card1` or `card2`), and directly modify `cardValue` from within the function, i.e.:

```js
  if (3 >= foo) {
    cardTotal += 11; // Add 11 to cardTotal
  } else {
  ...
```

Even Better: Have `cardTotal` return a value at the end of it.  That way, `cardTotal` still takes two values.  Modify its local value inside of the function scope, and then `return` that value back out of the function.

So, the last line of cardTotal should be `return bar;`

Then the last couple lines of your code snippet can be changed to:

```js
cardValue = cardTotal(card1, cardValue);
console.log(cardValue);
cardValue = cardTotal(card2, cardValue);
console.log(cardValue);
```

Comment: I would like to reuse cardTotal for multiple players so would need to kep 2 values. Even returning ```bar``` at the end of the function doesnt change the global variable

Comment: Sounds like you will want to return bar, so you can store the updated value per player  in another variable perhaps?  Returning bar won't change the global variable unless you assign the result of calling the cardTotal function into the global variable.

Comment: so i would have to make some other global variable and make it ```bee = return bar;```? Really appreciate the help though

Comment: okay i just set a new global variable and made the function ```bee += bar```. worked out great. thanks again for the help

Comment: Happy to help!!